# React/Momentjs date formatting with line break

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a date string that I want to format where the number is under the month:

```
Jul
 6
```

and I've tried a few different ways to add a new line:

```
<Moment format="MMM[\n]d">{`${date}`}</Moment>
```

but the result I'm getting is:

```
Jul\n6
```

Comment: I assume you're using npm react-moment

Comment: that's correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get Tholle's solution working with react-moment, you'll want to do the following:

```
<Moment style={{whiteSpace: "pre"}} format={"MMM[\n]d"}>{`${date}`}</Moment>
```

By putting your format within brackets, the `[\n]` will have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a line break by styling your element with [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```js
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = moment().format('MMM [\r\n] D')
```

```css
#root {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```