# How can I include plain text in a date format string?

Tags: javascript, antd

I am using `<Statistic.Countdown />` from Ant design to display the dates.

I'd like to achieve a format like: "2 years, 4 months, 5 days HH:mm:ss"

I have `format={"M months D HH:mm:ss"}`, but of course this interprets the "m" in months as the symbol for minutes, and so on: 3 42onth36 25 17:42:36.

How could I achieve "3 months 25 days 17:42:36"?

**Edit:** Thanks to Samathingamajig I got this working. Now I'm wondering, how can I insert a newline? I tried the following, but of course the second line will just show the full countdown in HH:mm:ss

```
  <Countdown title="Countdown" value={date} format={"M [months] D [days]"}/>
  <Countdown title="" value={date} format={"HH:mm:ss"}/>
```

I've tried using `\n` and `<br>`, both plain and enclosed in square brackets, to no effect.

Comment: Have you tried escaping? `format={"M \m\o\n\t\h\s D HH:mm:ss"}`

Comment: You'll probably want to implement something to change the pluralization of month/months for 1 month

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [docs](https://ant.design/components/statistic/), it formats it the same as moment.js, and if you go to [their documentation](https://momentjs.com/), you escape parts of the string with `[` and `]`.

To have newline, we have to [change the style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217763/12101554).

```js
style={{whiteSpace: "pre"}}
format={"M [months]\nD HH:mm:ss"}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/countdown-antd-4-18-5-forked-soh98

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my question, now I'm trying to figure out how to insert a newline or <br>

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik they've and I've tried that, it doesn't work, nor does the normal moment thing of adding `style={{ whiteSpace: "pre" }}`

Comment: @FromTheAshes Found a way to get newline in

Answer (score -2):

Try with single quotes like:

`format={"M 'months' D HH:mm:ss"}`

Comment: Doesn't work like that